# Удалить родительский елемент

Tags: javascript, html

Все привет, помогите разобраться. Суть, пишу ToDoList и столкнулся с проблемой удаления элементов списка. Удаление происходить, но не конкретного элемента, а самого первого.
Подскажите, как сделать, что бы удалялся конкретный элементов, в моем случае это тег р.

```js
let toDo = document.querySelector('.todo');
let count = 1;
let icon = "   <i class='fas fa-thumbtack' onclick='remove()' ></i>   ";

 
function add() {
  let btn = document.getElementById('add');
  let p = document.createElement('p'); 
  let inp = document.querySelector('#input').value;
  p.id = "myP";

    if (inp !=='') {
      p.innerHTML =  count + icon +inp;    
      toDo.appendChild(p);
      count++;
    } 
 
  }  

  function remove() {
    document.getElementById('myP').remove();
  }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">


<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>My First To Do List</h1>
    <div class="todo">
      <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Task" >
      <button id = "add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не повторяйте `id` элементов.

```
let icon = "   <i class='fas fa-thumbtack' onclick='remove(this)' ></i>   ";

...

  function remove(icon) {
    icon.closest('p').remove();
  }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!

Comment: @SumskyiVasyl Пожалуйста. Успехов!